# Circle with different colors

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-animation, geometry

I am new to Iphone. I want to draw a circle with different colors in it. And all the colors should cover equal area. Like if I want to have 10 different colors in it. Then each color should cover 1/10th area of the circle. I am not trying to draw a pie chart here. Also not trying to use 10 different colors. Just want 10 equal parts of circle and each part can be filled with colors.
I am trying to build a fortune wheel. Such that a smaller wheel is above the larger wheel. And then I want to drag them separately.
 Also is it possible to do this with help of Core Animation?

Comment: So it should almost look like a pie chart with ten pieces of equal size but not be a pie chart?

Comment: Do you need to animate the different parts in ay way (you are asking about Core Animation but don't mention any animations)?

Comment: Actually I am trying to build a fortune wheel. Such that a smaller wheel is above the larger wheel. And then I want to drag them seperately

Comment: So the circles themselves don't change their appearance, they only rotate around their center?

Comment: Yes they rotate around the center as we drag them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambiguous question. If you draw a piechart with 10 equal areas then each will cover 1/10th of the area, thus fulfilling your request, no?

There are 360° in a circle, so divide that by 10 and each wedge should have a 36°. Now you just have to draw 10 wedges, and this page should help you:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2106/core-graphics-101-arcs-and-paths

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you don't want pie slices, do you want concentric rings instead?

And are you sure you want equal AREA? That will make the rings different thicknesses. The innermost ring will be fairly thick, and each ring as you go outward will be thinner. Much thinner, on the outer rings.

Our eyes are used to a bulls-eye formation, where each ring is the same thickness.

In any case, you should look at CAShapeLayer objects. You can create a shape layer for each ring that defines a closed path with 2 circles. There is something called the "winding rule" that lets you determine what happens when paths overlap. I think you'd want even-odd path winding (kCAFillRuleEvenOdd).

To make the rings equal area, you could do this:

First calculate the area of the whole circle. Divide by the number of rings. That's the desired area for each ring Let's call that area "a". Start from the center. The radius of that ring (a circle) will be sqrt(pi/a).

For each following ring you'll need to calculate the thickness of the ring based on the area of the outer circle minus the area of the inner circle that makes up the ring. You'll need to write an equation that solves for the outer radius given the desired area and the radius or the previous circle.